# Squeeze/Sandwich Limit Theorem Absolute Value Variation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

We know that if given sequences (xn), (yn), and (wn), if (xn) and (yn) converge to a and xn ≤ wn ≤ yn, then wn converges to a.

Below is the proof
Fix ε > 0. We need to find an N such that |wn − a| < ε if n > N. Since (xn) → a and (yn) → a the definition of convergence ensures that there exists integers Nx and Ny so that |xn − a| < ε for n > Nx and |yn − a| < ε for n > Ny.

Let N=max(Nx, Ny). Then, for all n > N we have −ε < xn − a and yn − a < ε. Since xn < wn < yn, it follows that xn − a < wn − a < yn − a.

Thus if n ≥ N, then −ε < xn − a < wn − a < yn − a < ε. In other words, |wn − a| < ε.

**However, what if we have |xn| ≤ |wn| ≤ |yn|?**
Intuitively, the squeeze theorem would not hold. However, I can't think of a formal proof. Any help?

Comment: Do you want to know if this forces convergence of $w_n$ or $|w_n|$?

Comment: We know it forces convergence of wn trying to determine if it would force for |wn|.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x_n=1=y_n$ for all $n$.  Let $w_n = (-1)^n$.  Then everyone's absolute value converges to 1, but $\{w_n\}$ diverges.

Comment: This technically shows that it works for the absolute value version and similarly you could find a contradiction that it does not work. But I'm looking for a formal proof of if we have (xn) → a and (yn) → a and  |xn| ≤ |wn| ≤ |yn| then (wn) will not necessarily converge to a.

Comment: I don't follow.  A proof that something doesn't work is a single counterexample.  Also, my (and Niklas') example does exactly what you say in your last sentence.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - was looking for a proof using epsilonics. But yes both of what you and Niklas have posted makes sense - thank you!

Comment: Well, you can certainly use an $\varepsilon-N$ argument to show that $\{w_n\}$ fails to converge in our example, but I'm not sure what that teaches you.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $w_n=(-1)^n$ and $x_n=y_n=1$. Obviously the inequality holds but $(w_n)_n$ is not convergent.